# Saving constant values securely

Tags: android, properties, reverse-engineering, proguard

I am working on a Android application related to secure data communication. I am using a few constant values in my application, and am saving them in constant.java class. I don't want these values to be reverse engineered, but even though I am using ProGuard for Android, for experts it's easy to reverse the code. These constants are very secure. I can use properties file or any file in res folder but this approach is not at all secure.

Can anybody can tell me how to proceed? Is there any file format I can save my constants or prevent properties file from reverse engineered. Is there any option such as saving it in .py python file format and reading it from Android code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible to securely store secret constants on a device, since hackers can reverse engineer them through static and dynamic analysis. You can only make it a bit more difficult, by obfuscating the values:

- Compute them with some algorithm, instead of storing them literally. Even a trivial algorithm may increase the time needed to extract the constants.
- Distribute the components of the values throughout the code.
- Use native code. It is generally more difficult to reverse engineer, at least if the code and its API are sufficiently large and complex.
- Maybe look into whitebox cryptography, which tries to weave constant keys into the implementations of cryptographic algorithms, in such a way that the constant keys can't be extracted. This is still the realm of research and high-end commercial solutions.

You might get some ideas that you can apply yourself from [my presentation](http://www.saikoa.com/blog/DroidconLondon2013) and from [Scott Alexander-Bown's presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/scottyab/hardening-your-android-app-droidcon-uk-2013) at Droidcon in London.

You can also use a commercial obfuscator like the extended version of ProGuard, [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), to harden code for you, with techniques like string encryption and class encryption.

How effective the protection is depends on the time and effort that you can invest, on the value of your product, on the time and effort that hackers are willing to spend, on their expertise, etc.

Similar question: [Best Practice for storing private API keys in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-private-api-keys-in-android)

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: Maybe the security design is not good. Even with your advices, it is easy to add a line in the code (ex : Log.v(TAG, secretValue)) where it is ultimately used and just execute the app, it will print the value. A constant stored in the code/ressources of an app cannot be a secret.

Comment: This is bad advice. "Security by Obscurity" is top of the list of things to avoid by security researchers. The ACTUAL answer is to simply not keep secrets on the phone. A PKI infrastructure guarantees that even with the full sourcecode and access to stored keys an interloper can not passively steal data.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Dont do it!**. Secret constants are never secret. You should always assume your opponent is smart enough to reconstruct what you've hidden behind your smokescreen.

And anyway, you don't need to do it. For secure communications, instead use a public key infrastructure. Heres roughly how this works.

Your server generates a private and public key, and then you include the public key with your apps installation. It doesn't matter if the attacker finds this. All it allows is for your app to securely send a message to the server, and ONLY the server can decrypt it because only they have the private key.

So first thing your app should do is generate private and public key. Use whatever secure storage locker your OS provides to keep the private key safe. Its not invulnerable, but it's a damn lot more secure than anything you'll come up with. And then send the public key to your server.

Now you can securely send messages to the server using the servers public key, and the server can securely send messages to you using your public key.

Don't try reinventing the wheel here. Security researchers with serious qualifications in hard math and comp sci spend lifetimes coming up with these systems, and if you blow your implentation you leave it open for hackers to break in and steal your stuff. Use a widely trusted off the shelf PKI encryption library like OpenSSL and keep abreast of whatever source of security alerts covers that library.

Comment: I, instead, suggest DO every obfuscation and/or encryption and/or tamper check you are able to implement. The time and effort it takes to create the application deserves the highest protection possibile, in relation obviously of the type of the App. But I completely disappoint on suggesting "Dont do it" because there will be always someone able to hack the App... Instead, try to make the hacking process harder as possible.

Comment: Your completely missing the point. Obsfucation and symetric encryption (which requires having the key on the device) can be broken. The ACTUAL answer is dont store secrets on the phone at all. You don't ever need to, the technology exists to ensure you'll never need to do this, and its *vastly* more secure

Comment: Man it is frusturating that the advice giving attrocious security advice, obsfucate, is +6 and I've been downvoted for giving correct advice (Dont do it). Stack Overflow is usually smarter than this.

Comment: I can't remove the downvote unless you modify your answer. It's a SO's limitation.

Comment: Gah.... still irritated. The Snake Oil salesman got the green tick. 

Folks Dont spend money on obsfucators. I've never met one I cant reverse, at least enough to steal the prize. Further they tend to be a red flag to adversaries that theres secrets to plunder. Security by obscurity *never* works, and I dont care how convincing or how many upvotes it gets.