# Best way to store secret keys in Android applications

Tags: android, security, parse-platform, secret-key

I have a Parse account that I'm using to store user data for my Android application. Because I'm using source control, I don't want to leave my secret key embedded in the code. Is there a way to have a "config" file that I would keep out of source control, that can then host the key? If that's not feasible, what are the best practices of handling such a situation?

Comment: You're trying to keep the Parse keys secret from people with access to the source, but you don't mind distributing them with the application?  Anyone who's really interested could just decompile the apk and get the keys, right?

Comment: @nasch I was more concerned that this would prevent me from open-sourcing the project in the future. How would you handle this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Practice for storing private API keys in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-private-api-keys-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a folder outside of source control, put a file called app.properties in there, put your key in that properties file and add the folder to your build path. Then use a properties loader to load it from the classpath.

If you have many developers or more than one dev machine, you can set the local properties location as a variable in your build path so that each developer can configure their own.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the key in an environment variable and then read it during your build.

in your pom.xml declare a property (secret.key)

```
<properties>
   <secretKey>${env.SECRET_KEY}</secretKey>
<properties>
```

further down enable "[filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)" on your resources

```
  <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

In resources maintain a "config.properties" to read with the variable ready for substitution:

```
secret_key=${secretKey}
```

Filtering in maven will replace ${secret.key} with the value from your environment variable.

If you are using gradle for your build with Android studio see section [16.6.6.2 on filtering files](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html).

Within build.gradle add the following

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.FixCrLfFilter
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task copyProductionConfig(type: Copy) {
  from 'source'
  include 'config.properties'
  into 'build/targetpath/config'
  expand([
    secretKey: System.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

  ])
}
```

In gradle you can also request input when you run gradlew using

```
Console console = System.console()
def password = console.readPassword("Enter Secret Key: ")
```

And then apply it to the appropriate config or source files.