# Rest API key between activities Android

Tags: android, rest, android-activity, android-volley

**Background**

I designed a rest API that acts as a interface between my Android app and MySQL database. As a user logs in to the app, an API key is returned from the database by the API in form of JSON object (along with other details). Volley parses the SON object and retrieves the API key. All the further calls to the API are made after the API key is authenticated in request header.

**Problem**

I want to know the best way to store the parsed API key to a variable which can be used by all the activities globally to send requests to API through volley.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I'd probably store it in the REST client class and either get it from there or pass it to the activities through the Intent

Answer (score 1):

1. SharedPreferences could be the place to store it, than you can
   retrieve it whenever needed.
2. Or you can call your API every time app starts, in Application class
   onCreate() for example, and store it there as member variable

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big 'best practice' question, and so you're going to get a lot of different answers.  I like to use ProGuard as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-private-api-keys-in-android) SO question.  If you're not interested in dealing with all that at the moment though, SharedPreferences are a good place to start.