# How to secure implemented url in my code android?

Tags: java, android, url

I created an application on android. I use some Url to request on my server, but I do not know how to secure or hide those Urls in my app code. I have apk decompile so there code in displaying url so how to hide url. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's not even necessary to decompile your program to get the URL, one can just sniff network traffic to see it.

Comment: i also facing similar problem.. is that any way to resolve this issue if yes then let me know

Answer (score 0):

According to @[marcinj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571260/6339705) The best way to Keep your secrets on some server on internet.
First request will go to with some identical token if server match token then response other all secret urls or data.