# Android Server Communication Security

Tags: android, api, server, decompiling, source-code-protection

A few days ago one person decompiled my app and show me an issue in my source code. I was hardcoding the links and the password of my server in source code of the app, I didn't know through decompiling anyone can see my source code. I use proguard but proguard doesn't obfuscate strings. This left me wondering how is the right way to do this? How can my app make api calls and the server can authenticate it? I did a research but I did't see much content talking about this. My app doesn't manage users and passwords. The user and password that I store in my code are the ones to login in the server.

Comment: I believe you are referring to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-private-api-keys-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pretty easy to see decompiled Java code to get keys and the like.

There are a few things to do:

1. Ensure the "application keys" or "tokens" are not a secret with deep admin privileges. Many SaaS / API Providers give you multiple keys. One is a client key that is limited in privileges/actions that can be performed, and a server key that has more privileges but won't be leaked out via client code. In you case, you shouldn't share the same server login/admin passwords. Leverage Principle of least privilege (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)
2. Ensure the string is a static final. In this case, Compiler and Proguard which allow string inlining. This makes it a little harder to know what the string is for. If you have a single "Config" class, it's pretty easy to search for 'facebook' in facebookAppId, 'secret' googleSecret, etc.
3. To be really secure, you can perform some encryption, or other algorithm on the string, but this means you also store the encryption secret in the code itself also.

In general, I believe (1) gives the most since you should always assume any string in client can be found/hacked, whether Android/Java with Proguard or minified javascript.