# I need the best way to protect my data in android app

Tags: android

I need the best way to protect my data ,I don't want any one to arrive to the data in my app even he can get the api .
I heard that any one can decompile app and take the data !!
How can I protect it from app side and also from web side ?

thanx in advance.

Comment: Here are some links which help you.
1) https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html
2) https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#androidapplication

Answer (score 3):

Use Proguard.

1. You need to remove Log messages.
2. Set `minifyEnabled` to true in your app's `build.gradle` file.
3. Set rules for obfuscation

This will shrink your code too much so that your code wouldn't be human readable. But, people can still decompile it.

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989), for API Keys and other private data.

Comment: I didn't understand !!u mean that this way will protect my data if any one can decompile the code?!!

Comment: The *obfuscates* code, it doesn't prevent decompilation, just makes it harder

Comment: I need to protect my data in app not the code !! I mean no one can steal my data >>

Comment: they wouldn't understand your code. For e.g. if you have `getStringFromFile()` method in your code, they might see it as `gsff();` which is totally unreadable.

Comment: What about API keys? And URL strings? Those can't be obfuscated.

Comment: what about apis ?
if he reach to it he can get the data !!

Comment: I mean data that i get from apis not code !!
I don't care about code

Comment: @cricket_007 if the code itself, classes, methods, variables are obfuscated: it will already be hard to read it. And, no one will decompile his app until its big Hit or featured

Comment: I'm just saying it's not impossible to get access to the code and potentially some data without additional measures like encryption.

Comment: edited my answer, for api keys and private data, proguard is still helpful

Answer (score 0):

The best way to protect your data is to only allow authenticated users access their own data and data that can't be used in a harmful way i.e. not other users data.
In that way it doesn't matter if the user access the API with his/her own user credentials.