# Avoid decompiling android APK

Tags: android, proguard, decompiling, android-proguard

How to prevent my APK from decompiling? I have enabled proguard but still, I can decompile APK. Is there any way to build APK that cannot be decompiled? Or any way to store the constant value that cannot be identified when APK is decompiled?

Comment: It's not possible. If the attacker has access to the compiled code, they can decompile it. What you can do, is make it a client/server app, and keep the secret parts on the server side.

Comment: Then how to transfer encryption keys safely?

Comment: Hm... maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570989/812149) can help. For the encryption, consider a public-key encryption scheme. Communication between the app and a server should be secured using SSL/TLS, which has public-key encryption built in.

Comment: Ok. I will try some key exchange patterns.