# Correct way of storing API Keys in flutter following best practises

Tags: dart, flutter

Which is the correct way(*best practice*) of adding secret API keys in flutter in case I want to push the code on github. I've made a simple app that consumes an API but I used the key in a crud way just to test whether the app is working. Usually from my experience developing applications in the back-end, Keys are stored somewhere and in different file then one would simply import it to the required file that needs the `API_KEY` and exclude the file in `.gitignore` file.

So far I have also implemented this approach:

#### Folder tree

```
-lib
  -auth
    -keys.dart
    -secrets.json
```

## secrets.json

This is where I will add the `KEY` and specify this file in `.gitignore` to be excluded from being added in github when I push my code.

```
//Add API KEY HERE
{
  "api_key": "ee4444444a095fc613c5189b2"
}
```

## keys.dart

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;


class Secret {
  final String apikey;

  Secret({this.apikey=""});

  factory Secret.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>jsonMap){
    return new Secret(apikey:jsonMap["api_key"]);
  }
}


class SecretLoader {
  final String secretPath;

  SecretLoader({this.secretPath});
  Future<Secret> load() {
    return rootBundle.loadStructuredData<Secret>(this.secretPath,
            (jsonStr) async {
          final secret = Secret.fromJson(json.decode(jsonStr));
          return secret;

        });
  }
}
```

I feel like this approach is too much. I would like to get suggestions of a better approach.

Comment: If this shouldn't be shared; ideally it shouldn't be on the client. Ultimately once you ship your app, peoples can just decompile it to get everything within.

Comment: I'm using an API that requires me to add the key  so that I get the payload I need. The app is consuming the API and add a key is required to access the payload. Where can I store the keys so that I access them when needed?

Comment: I like this method of doing things. I've done very similar things in my apps. I will also make a `main_dev.dart` and `main_prod.dart` -- each file will be targeted for running that version of the app. In each file, i will import the corresponding `secrets.json` and use it throughout the app.

Comment: how are you actually retrieving the api key string in your code?

Comment: if you rely on gitignored file with secrets, just make a dart file with `static const` keys. Much easier to use

Comment: **@RémiRousselet your comment is misleading and INCORRECT!** API Keys **MUST be hard coded!** That's how you connect your app to a Firebase project and any other cloud services. If you want to prevent reverse engineering, use obfuscation. For more information and links to official resources, please check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455722/12695188

Comment: but isn't this negligent for production apps to do? In other words if I want to provide a secure app to my user's I always need to build my own backend, thus making all flutter setups provided by google obscure?

Answer (score 20):

## API Keys must be hard coded.

### Why?

Because it's impossible to retrieve the key from an external source without having a key to that source, and you can't store it securely at the OS level without having the key within the app.

### Example

When you connect your app to a Firebase project or Google Cloud servers, you basically authenticate using a hard-coded API key, that you have downloaded into your app when initiating your cloud project ([read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#find-api-keys)).

### Security

There are **two essential steps** to secure your critical assets:

1. Keep your secret keys [out of version control](https://medium.com/podiihq/keeping-secret-keys-out-of-version-control-in-flutter-bcd2b1eb9c1b).
2. Use [obfuscation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate) to make it difficult for attackers to reverse engineer your application, and reveal your API Key.

IMO, those are the only steps you can take to secure your app API Key.

Comment: Agreed, best answer. Though, I might [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73537429/13945484)

Comment: For anyone seeing this now, check @RobbB's answer and my clarification before deciding if this is good enough.

Answer (score 8):

For secure storage you have to rely on the corresponding native platforms, both iOs and Android provide a mechanism to securely store keys. You can implement it by yourself and use the flutter channels to obtain and store the keys. Information about this mechanism can be read here:

[Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)

[iOs KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1)

Also, you can use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage) flutter plugin, which uses the services mentioned above and provides a dart object to access the secure storage.

Comment: This does not help since you'd put the API Secret in the code at some point and decompiling the APK would still reveal the Secret!!!

Comment: Agree with @AryeeteySolomonAryeetey. **This is a bad answer.**

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: Look at Sludge's comment below.**

EDIT 2: The issue in described at the bottom has been fixed in `firebase-config 19.0.2`.

<strike>Use `Firebase Remote Config`.</strike> Inside the Firebase console, inside the menu, scroll down to `Grow` and then `Remote Config`. Here you can add a parameter with a value. When you're done don't forget to publish the changes. It's kind of subtle.

[image]

Now install [firebase_remote_config](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config) for Flutter.

After importing everything, you can retrieve your value using this code:

```dart
RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: Duration(hours: 1));
await remoteConfig.activateFetched();

remoteConfig.getValue('key').asString();
```

This way, the API key or token is never part of your application.

**Note:** there is currently an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/254) where you get a warning stating the application's name is not set, but this won't affect functionality.

Comment: I like this strategy.  However, then you have documentation like https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#getting-started that tells people to place the API KEY in `AndroidManifest.xml` or `AppDelegate.m`.  Is this not bad practice?  How should one replace this strategy?

Comment: Per Firebase: "Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or parameter values. It is possible to decode any parameter keys or values stored in the Remote Config settings for your project." (https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config)

Comment: Any suggestion on how this can done. Do you think that  firebase realtime/datastore is a better choice?

Comment: **This is a bad answer**, since in order to connect to Firebase project, you have to download a hard coded API_Key first. In other words, this approach is meaningless and misleading. https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#find-api-keys

Comment: @genericUser do you have a better solution?

Comment: Of course! :) Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455722/12695188

Comment: Firebase Remote Config documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config#policies_and_limits) we can read the following: Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or parameter values. It is possible to decode any parameter keys or values stored in the Remote Config settings for your project.  So this answer should be marked as not valid

Comment: Dunno! Since I've started work in mobile apps using Firebase solutions in 2018, I've seen how it's easy to attackers to get information when a device calls Remote Config. Besides each device waits 4 hours to recall Remote Config (except when you reinstall the app in your device), but this is not the default average user case. A regular user in production updates his/her app from Play Store/App Store instead of uninstall then download from stores. It it was a good way to do that remotely, it would be in Realtime Database, which is "real time" and it's not charged per requests.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, if the key is a secrete and you would like to protect it then simply do not put it in the client app. The app can be de-compiled and the key can be extracted for person willing to target your client.

I would delegate the task of communicating with this API to your Application Server. You can put the key in your server and have your server communicate with this external API and relay the response to the client.

Edit: Another approach, which is less secure but more convenient is to obfuscate your code using something like proguard. See this page for flutter instruction on android app: https://flutter.io/android-release/

Comment: I do not want to invest extra time building a back-end server  for this, I did my research and found out  how android  handles this when building it with java :(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications). There must be a way  for  flutter  to handles this. Also here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android

Comment: But if you request the API from your own server everyone will be able to do that if they know the URI that they could again retrieve from your code.

Comment: **This is a bad answer.** There is not other option then saving the API Key hard-coded on the client side. That's the hole idea behind API keys.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice should be to [create a Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), and then have that function use the secrets storage.   This approach keeps the secrets out of  your source code so there are no issues with sharing the code, and stores them securely.   Firebase authenticates your app (and users if you use the login feature).

[Secret Parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret_parameters)

[Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#dart)

Answer (score 1):

You should never put API keys into your client apps (unless they are marked as public keys), as mentioned above they are now compromised and could be used in malicious context. Additionally, it's generally a good idea to be able to roll-over api-keys, secret-keys periodically. Embedding them into your client apps just about kills that notion without some complex mechanism that in-itself will be an anti-pattern.

What we should be doing:

1. Have an Authentication flow, where your client side inherits an identity of the end user, be it a custom email auth, sign-in with Provider auth (Google, Facebook)...
2. If using a Provider, like Google Oauth2, don't put your Provider secret key in the client app (tutorials on this are generally not great. Only embed keys when the provider explicitly says you can), the code<=>token exchange should occur on the server-side when the secret key is necessary, or when you want to validate id_tokens.
3. Send back to your client a Bearer token that represents their
   identity. This is all to limit scope of what secret is exposed to the end user. Bearer tokens must not contain sensitive information and must be signed (if your going to send back your own).
4. Create a server-side implementation(s) for negotiation between API's and your Clients. Your Client app call your back-end API with their Identity Token, your back-end service call the API with secret and pass through results back to the client app.

As far as the backend, server-side impl. It can be as simple as a server-less function such as an AWS Lambda + API Gateway (1Million executions a month for free from Lambda). Or you can host larger, more complex service backends if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A way of storing API Keys safely in flutter local repository from not being uploaded to a remote repository, is to use dart package flutter_dotenv, here I put the link of the package with all the information about it [link to package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

You can use [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) from the oficial Flutter Packages

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but when using this package, I will still rely on putting the keys in my source code, since they eventually have to be added to the secure storage at some point, so I can read them later. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I think you understand it correctly. That package helps if you get secrets from your *user* and want to store them safely.