# 'Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value' on pressing card

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this problem with navigation, when ever I press this card I get this error `Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value` in debug console. Whenever I press cards if not logged in I must navigate to `UrlScreen`

```
 void tapped(int index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        bool isBaseUrlEntered = StoreDetails.checkBaseUrlEnteredSession(
            StoreDetails.isBaseUrlEntered);
        print(isBaseUrlEntered);
        if (isBaseUrlEntered) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SplashScreen(nameType: "Pre Sales")),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UrlScreen(nameType: "Pre Sales")),
          );
        }
      } else if (index == 3) {
        bool isProjectBaseUrlEntered =
            ProjectMgmtStoreDetails.checkProjectBaseUrlEnteredSession(
                ProjectMgmtStoreDetails.isProjectBaseUrlEntered);
        print(isProjectBaseUrlEntered);
        if (isProjectBaseUrlEntered) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SplashScreen(nameType: "Project Mgmt")),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UrlScreen(nameType: "Project Mgmt")),
          );
        }
```

And the full error in debug console is

```
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      ProjectMgmtStoreDetails.checkProjectMgmtLoginSession (package:bhoomi/utils/store_details_project_mgmt.dart:43:27)
#1      WelcomeScreenState.build.tapped (package:bhoomi/screens/welcome_screens/welcome_screen.dart:113:49)
#2      WelcomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:bhoomi/screens/welcome_screens/welcome_screen.dart:366:48)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
#7      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#8      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
#9      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#10     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#12     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#13     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#14     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#19     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#1a171
```

Edit base on Grekkq suggestion

```
class ProjectMgmtStoreDetails {
  static const isProjectMgmtLoggedIn = 'isProjectMgmtLoggedIn';
  static const isProjectBaseUrlEntered = 'isProjectBaseUrlEntered';
  static const projectMgmt = 'projectMgmt';
  static const name = 'name';
  static const projectNameList = 'projectNameList';
  static const valuationList = 'valuationList';
  static const projectAuthUrl = 'projectAuthUrl';
  static const projectBaseUrl = 'projectBaseUrl';
  static const title = 'title';
  static const userId = 'userid';
  static const typeList = 'typeList';
  static const verbList = 'verbList';
  static const staffName = 'staffName';
  static const staffId = 'staffId';
  static const notificationDetailList = 'notificationDetailList';
  static const fromDateFilter = 'fromDateFilter';
  static const toDateFilter = 'toDateFilter';
  static const valuationFilter = 'valuationFilter';
  static const valuationIdFilter = 'valuationIdFilter';
  static const projectId = 'projectId';
  static const vendorName = 'vendorName';
  static const vendorId = 'vendorId';

  static Future<SharedPreferences?>? get _instance1 async => _prefsInstance1!;
  static SharedPreferences? _prefsInstance1;

  static Future<SharedPreferences?>? init() async {
    _prefsInstance1 = await _instance1;
    return _prefsInstance1!;
  }

  // for project mgmt credentials
  static bool? checkProjectMgmtLoginSession(String key) {
    return _prefsInstance1?.getBool(key);
  }

  static Future<bool> createProjectMgmtLoginSession() async {
    var prefs = await _instance1;
    return prefs!.setBool(isProjectMgmtLoggedIn, true);
  }

  //for base url session
  static bool checkProjectBaseUrlEnteredSession(String key) {
    return _prefsInstance1!.getBool(key) ?? false;
  }

  static Future<bool> createProjectBaseUrlEnteredSession() async {
    var prefs = await _instance1;
    return prefs!.setBool(isProjectBaseUrlEntered, true);
  }

  // for project mgmt
  static Future<bool> setProjectMgmtToken(String value) async {
    var prefs = await _instance1;
    return prefs!.setString(projectMgmt, value);
  }

  static String getProjectMgmtToken(String key) {
    return _prefsInstance1!.getString(key) ?? "";
  }

  static Future<bool> setLoggedInUserName(String value) async {
    var prefs = await _instance1;
    return prefs!.setString(name, value);
  }

  static String getLoggedInUserName(String key) {
    return _prefsInstance1!.getString(key) ?? "";
  }

so on
```

Comment: You should add content of the `store_details_project_mgmt.dart`. Also why you pass to the `checkProjectBaseUrlEnteredSession` something that is already inside this class?

Answer (score 0):

The `Null check operator used on a null value` exception message usually occurs when you use `!` operator on a nullable instance which wasn't initialized. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990442/12444149) for further explanation.

Looking at the stack you can see that probably the `ProjectMgmtStoreDetails` class is problematic. If you are using modern IDE you should be able to `CTRL+Click` on the line number in you exception message and it should take you where the exception occurred.

I would also suggest to not store any authentication/other secrets details in your app code, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895194/correct-way-of-storing-api-keys-in-flutter-following-best-practises) for potential solution.