# How to secure flutter app from decompile or sniffing?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm curious if there is a way to decompile and access flutter codes from a release apk? and how to prevent that? if there is no way to prevent, so how to keep data securely?
In my case i have to keep user name and a password static , how can i secure them and prevent them to be accessed?
It's just an android version not ios.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of safely storing a secret in your dart code, it will always be possible to reverse engineer the apk and find the secret. [See this question for better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895194/correct-way-of-storing-api-keys-in-flutter-following-best-practises).

The main question is then: Why do you need to hard code a username and a password? Maybe another way is possible that does not require to have access to this information in the app. Having a backend which does all the requests to the authenticated service you want to access can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your case maybe you can check the code below. [The code source](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box)

```
void main() async {
  const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  // if key not exists return null
  final encryptionKeyString = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  if (encryptionKeyString == null) {
    final key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    await secureStorage.write(
      key: 'key',
      value: base64UrlEncode(key),
    );
  }
  final key = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  final encryptionKeyUint8List = base64Url.decode(key!);
  print('Encryption key Uint8List: $encryptionKeyUint8List');
  final encryptedBox = await Hive.openBox('vaultBox', encryptionCipher: HiveAesCipher(encryptionKeyUint8List));
  encryptedBox.put('secret', 'Hive is cool');
  print(encryptedBox.get('secret'));
}
```

From that code, you generate a random `secure key` that will be used to encrypt and decrypt a data with AES Encryption. From the code, there are two storage libraries, [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). Since the flutter_secure_storage is good for security, the random security key will be saved using this library. And the Hive is good for fast and light databases. A combination of both libraries will be good to achieve your case.

Also, check this article. The article is a good guide to help increase the security of the Flutter app.

https://medium.com/kbtg-life/mobile-security-via-flutter-ep-1-ssl-pinning-c57f18b711f6

https://medium.com/kbtg-life/70b4322bffc2

I followed several guidelines from the article so that my application passed the penetration test.