# How to stop identifying web service request in charles proxy tool android

Tags: android, encryption

I am consuming apis in android application , if i use charles proxy tool or wireshark, i can able to see what request is hitting. If i know what request is going, somebody should hit this web service unnecessarily to increase server load.How can i stop this.Is there any way to encrypt these apis or securely hit same webserver request again.

Comment: A public API is a public API. You can obfuscate your app but that only increases the effort to find the API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for storing and protecting private API keys in applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications)