# How to hide API keys in Android application?

Tags: android, environment-variables, api-key

In my application I use google maps api key to communicate with google. I defined this MAP_KEY in gradle debug/release configuration like this:

```
debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://myweb.com"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SOCKET_URL', '"https://socket.myweb.com"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MAP_KEY', '"azaS****Ds"'
        }
```

But If someone will download my app from google play store and decompile it he will get my API tokens. Is this true? If yes what is the way to hide api keys in my code?

Comment: Check this link: https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Comment: Thanks! I read. So we don't have any good practice to hide keys except use it on backend side only?

Comment: I would recommend to use NDK layer for storing secrets. It's much harder to retrieve a secret from C++ library then from Java/Kotlin class. You could use https://github.com/nomtek/android-client-secrets library for that.

Comment: I would recommend to use NDK layer for storing secrets. It's much harder to retrieve a secret from C++ library then from Java/Kotlin class. You could use https://github.com/nomtek/android-client-secrets library for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice for storing and protecting private API keys in applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **Short answer :**

Obfuscate or Encrypt your google map API key according to [Google Map Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) :

> On mobile apps that use Maps Web Service APIs, consider one or more    of the following techniques to further safeguard your apps and API
> keys:
>
> - Apply an API restriction on the API key. This action narrows the    scope of the API key to the APIs you associate with the key.
>   Obfuscate or encrypt the API key. This action complicates key
>   scraping attempts directly from the application.
> - Use CA pinning or certificate pinning to verify the server resources    are valid. CA pinning checks that a server's certificate
>   was issued    by a trusted certificate authority, and prevents
>   Man-In-The-Middle    attacks that could lead to a third party
>   discovering your API key.    Certificate pinning goes further by
>   extracting and checking the    public key included in the server
>   certificate. Pinning is useful for    mobile clients communicating
>   directly with Google servers, as well as    mobile clients
>   communicating with the developer's own proxy server.
> - Use a proxy server.

You can use many encryption or obfuscation ways you can find easily with just a quick search, One common way is to base64 encoding the key in C++ as a library and to use it just call a function in your Java class, because C++ codes after compiling is more hard to decompile than your Java classes.

[**Tutorial of doing it with NDK**](https://medium.com/programming-lite/securing-api-keys-in-android-app-using-ndk-native-development-kit-7aaa6c0176be)

### Long Answer: IT DEPENDS

You can not do anything in client side to proof your code against decompiling and specially make one hard coded string immune to get extracted.

**So what you should do ?**

It's a trade-off, at First you should see how much your Key is important for you, Who will try to access it and how much time it worth for him to put on hacking your app. With Encryption or obfuscation we just make it harder, So we need more professional person with more time to hack it(Basically with every layer of security we add to it we are doing that.)

If it's too secret and if It's leak will have cause many problem for you and it's critical you should store it in a server, Then you should request to that server and that server will do API call with your key Or with something like a JWT Token.

**But** in case of Google Map API as long as you monitor it and configure it correctly, leaking your key will not cause many problems for you.

Comment: In case of Google Map key we can do not worry because in Google Map console we specified Application package ID which can send request with this token. Right?

Comment: @Nastro That can be spoofed too but not enough, It is another level of security but it does not make it fully secure. But at least it does not allow other google play legit applications to use your API key.