# I want to save a static key and need to send in header, what is best and secure place in android app?

Tags: android

I want to save a static key and later I need to send it with as a header for https request, where I can put it securely in android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for storing and protecting private API keys in applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications)

Comment: Please check out this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) in Android. Read the documentation

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
    commit()
}


val defaultValue = resources.getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key)
val highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue)
```

Comment: friendly tip. link-only answers are not seen as answers and will typically be down-voted. consider giving a possible example of this or move this to a comment. Remember, links can change

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, I want to prevent a hacker from accessing any resources.

Comment: Then use google cloud project to store you Key and you have to make a call every time you call your own service.

Comment: another way is you can right your own encryption and decryption and use the Shared preference.

Comment: thanks for reply @hfarhanahmed, can I use aws KMS for that purpose because We are paying a huge amount to amazon.

Comment: Also I don't think if anyone re engineer your apk, they can't get your shared preference values. They can just get the code. get the key from api when the app starts and store it in shared preference and you are good