# How to securely store API keys in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables, dart-pub

I'm using the [googleapi](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis)'s Flutter package and to use the Google Drive API, I need to put in credentials. My question is, how can I securely store them in my app so when I publish my app, they can't be taken. I found a cool package, [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) but to use it, I need to put all of my values into the secure storage. So how can I do that? I was thinking of using something like [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/use-environment-variables-in-ci-cd-for-flutter-apps-cbd6d9ac82c), but I'm not sure. It would be great if someone could put me in the right direction as to how to do this by the book so to speak.

To further explain, I don't want to have my sensitive information in a file such as `main.dart` as a variable to put into storage (if it isn't there already).

Comment: [android - Best practice for storing and protecting private API keys in applications - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using the flutter_dotenv package.
Create a `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
GOOGLE_API = API_KEY
```

Add the `.env` file to your assets bundle in `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
  - .env
```

Add the `.env` file as an entry in your `.gitignore` if it isn't already

```
.env*
```

Access variables from `.env` throughout the application

```
DotEnv().env['GOOGLE_API'];
```

Read more on how to install and use the package [here: flutter_dotenv](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv)

Comment: Any way this will be bundled with APK if you generate the one. And it can be easily retrieve during the reverse engineering of the APK.. .

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan, that's just no possible. any api keys stored on device can be hacked. if you can't have your keys compromised, you'll have to keep them in the backend server instead.

Comment: @Lucas Chwe But if I put a network debugger like Fiddler I can check the endpoint and replicate the request to get the API key.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to create a database to store your keys. You can set up a small backend connected to your base that you contact, So you can implement all the security you want.
This is the safest way

Comment: Sounds like you'll have the same problem all over again, with your backend.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to store secret credentials in the app. Think other way around and secure the API key with appropriate permissions from the google cloud platform.

Secure storage is intended for user content.