# Android : Protecting resources

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a game right now and I am using Android Studio for it.

I have a security concern for the resources that I will be using (images, music, etc.), and I would like to know if it's possible to protect these using proguard? I have no experience of decoding but I always enable proguard when releasing my apps.

Comment: I could be mistaken so I'm not posting as an answer, but I think someone would be able to get your assets... If keeping them safe is important you may want to implement your own encryption for your assests

Comment: But then you will still have to compile it with the decryption key and they will still be able to retrieve the files

Comment: yes but you can try hiding the keys with these methods: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570989/9779471