# How can I protect an android app (it has some communication with a backend server)

Tags: android, google-play

I'm going to release an android app shortly on the Google Playstore. I am aware that most apps probably don't reach the level of success where the authors need to worry about their app being cloned, but I would still have greater peace of mind if I knew that I had done what I can to stop other people copying it/stealing users by creating an identical knock-off.

I suspect that it's unproductive to try to protect the app itself (?) but my app communicates quite a lot with a backend server and I'm wondering if there are ways to detect if I am getting traffic from my app or a copy? Is there any value I can get the app to send that could tell me, or some technique I could use to differentiate my app from copies?

Thank you

Comment: Have an API key and obfuscate it as best as you can, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989/best-practice-for-storing-and-protecting-private-api-keys-in-applications).

Answer (score 0):

Read the below article at developer.android.com.It provides details on how to obfuscate your app.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate