# is there a Regex to toggle Character case in a String?

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a string like

```
var str = "AbCdEfGhIj"
```

that i want to toggle each character casing, that is,

convert it to `var str = "aBcDeFgHiJ"`

i am currently using this code below

```
val bytes = "HEllo WoRLd".toByteArray()
// Swap upper and lower case letters.
    for (i in bytes.indices) {
        if (bytes[i] >= 'A'.toByte() && bytes[i] <= 'Z'.toByte())
            bytes[i] = ('a'.toInt() + (bytes[i] - 'A'.toByte())).toByte()
        else if (bytes[i] >= 'a'.toByte() && bytes[i] <= 'z'.toByte())
            bytes[i] = ('A'.toInt() + (bytes[i] - 'a'.toByte())).toByte()
    }
 System.out.print(String(bytes)) // heLLO wOrlD
```

Wondering if there's a regex that can do this

Comment: Regex is used for pattern matching. I don't think it can be used for toggling the case.

Comment: … Besides, it already looks okay. I'd rather optimize code readability a bit, but overall it's okay.

Comment: I mean its doable. But it will unnecessarily make it more complex and affect performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say, regexes are for matching, not altering.

But the code in the question can be improved; it will fail for non-ASCII characters (and is unnecessarily complex).  Here's a more elegant version, as an extension function on `String`:

```
fun String.swapCase() = map {
    when {
        it.isUpperCase() -> it.toLowerCase()
        it.isLowerCase() -> it.toUpperCase()
        else -> it
    }
}.joinToString("")

println("HEllo WoRLd".swapCase()) // heLLO wOrlD
```